# I created an audio echo signal in matlab using fft: Is it a true "echo?"

Tags: matlab, audio, fft

This is just an outline of what I did (assume that all my dimensions fit):

```
    (code that imports audio to read audio as function x)
    X=fft(x);
    (code to define time t and frequency f)

    H=L+M*exp(-1i*2*pi*f*N)+O*exp(-1i*2*pi*f*P);
    % This is where it gets tricky 
    % In the frequency domain I have the function above where f is the frequency 
    % variable and L M N O P are arbitrary values

    Y=X.*H;   
    % again assume dimensions fit

    y=real(ifftshift(ifft(Y)*length(t)));
    %Taking the inverse fft and fftshift was the only way I could get back a signal
    % Once again assume the dimensions fit
```

I would post pictures, but I need at least 10 rep:
I'll do my best to describe in the following:

```
   | 
   ||       
   |||||  
   ||     
   |
```

This is my Original input signal x

```
      |      |
    |||      |||
      |      |
```

This is my output y

(Now if I heaviside(t-t0) output y and add it to the original I get the following)

```
   | 
   ||        |
   |||||     |||
   ||        | 
   |
```

Is this legit? or am I just pulling my own leg?

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally, your working with the right sort of tools to create an echo, so what you're getting is reasonable.  Consider that an echo can be described and the convolution of an input signal with a delta function.

$$Y(t) = X(t) \ast \delta(t-t_{echo})$$

In the frequency domain, the convolution is expressed as multiplication.  Also, the delta function becomes a wave $e^{i 2 \pi t_{echo} f}$. see the wiki on Fourier Transforms http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform.  Your H function is basically three of these waves corresponding to deltas (the constant is $e^{i 2 \pi 0 f}$.).  When you multiply your `X` by `H`, you're copying and translating `x`. So, in the time domain, you should be getting three copies of your signal proportional to `O`,`M`, and  `L`.

Once you've got those general concepts down, then you need to focus on the details of implementation.  Pay close attention to how you're defining frequency to make sure that it matches the points generated by the FFT.  A great way to test if you're unsure about your implementation is to build it up incrementally.  Set `H=1`, at that point your output should match your input.  Then try only one wave and verify that you're getting the exact echo that you expect.  In general, it may be easier to test and check by using a more simple input signal (a pure cos or maybe cos with an envelope that lets you see shifts easily).

Comment: I have already found the solution. I posted this answer and solution in dsp section.

Comment: I just took the time to read what you were saying, and I agree with you. I should of asked in dsp section since I already know the math associated with Fourier Analysis. Here is the [link](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/17404/created-matlab-echo-signal-is-it-an-actual-echo-or-am-i-just-manipulating-th)